# Problem in writing overline

Tags: equations, subequations

I am trying to write this:
[image]

This is what I wrote:

```
$\pi$'$\cdot$role = $\overline{$\pi$$\cdot$role}$
```

### But I am getting errors:

> paper.tex(37): Error: Missing } inserted. paper.tex(37): Error:
>   Missing $ inserted. paper.tex(37): Error: Extra }, or forgotten
>   \endgroup. paper.tex(37): Error: LaTeX Error: Command \end{definition}
>   invalid in math mode. paper.tex(37): Error: LaTeX Error: Something's
>   wrong--perhaps a missing \item. paper.tex(37): Error: LaTeX Error:
>   Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. paper.tex(37): Error:
>   Missing $ inserted. paper.tex(50): Overfull \hbox (10.83658pt too
>
> ### wide) in paragraph at lines 50--51

How can I fix this please?

Comment: you have to much `$` signs ... omit all of them between the first and the last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
    \begin{document}
\begin{preview}
In case of in-line equation you should write $\pi'\cdot\mathit{role} = \overline{\pi\cdot\mathit{role}}$, however in case in displaymath equation as
\[
\pi'\cdot\mathit{role} = \overline{\pi\cdot\mathit{role}}
\]
\end{preview}
    \end{document}
```

**Note:** The `...{preview}`  is used for showing only desired fragment of page:

[image]

In document production all had to be removed.

**Edit:** 
It is not clear what is "role". Probably it would be better that it will be written as:

```
$\pi'\cdot\mathrm{role} = \overline{\pi\cdot\mathrm{role}}$
```

(as indicate David Carlisle in his erased answer)

[image]